# Conan OpenAL-Soft Package Installation Issue: 'settings.compiler' value not defined Question:

Tags: installation, conan

I am encountering an issue while trying to install the OpenAL-Soft package using Conan. The error message I'm receiving is as follows:

```
openal-soft/1.22.2: Error in validate() method, line 74
        if self.settings.compiler.get_safe("cppstd"):
        ConanException: 'settings.compiler' value not defined
```

Does anyone has a clue what can I do ?

I updated conan using the following line:

```
pip install --upgrade conan
```

I also checked my conan profile

```
Detected profile:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
build_type=Release
os=Windows
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `openal-soft` recipe requires having a compiler defined, this is why it is complaining with `ConanException: 'settings.compiler' value not defined`.

Indeed, your profile doesn't have a compiler defined. This is typically because you don't have a c++ compiler installed in the system or it is not in a default location, path, or discoverable by the Conan profile detection. You should try installing a compiler and then doing forcing the profile detection again. Or defining your own profile file and passing it with `conan ... -pr=myprofile` to the command line.

Comment: I have installed Clang and made a toolset. unfortunately there is still a problem for CLion. Thank you very for helping me making progress. Could you also tell me what this means? CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindSFML.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "SFML", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "SFML" (requested
  version 2.5) with any of the following names:
Do I need to add something to Path in Windows ?

Comment: For support-like, it is much better to use https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues, because it is easier to have a conversation and iterate there.